# "comi uma francesinha no Porto e achei uma delícia" Do que se trata?

Tags: significado, diferenças-transatlânticas

Ouvi, no aeroporto, uma turista dizer alto e bom som que comeu uma francesinha. Fosse um turista, do sexo masculino, eu não pensaria duas vezes.  Mas, no caso em questão, todos riram e acredito tratar-se de uma armadilha linguística para os brasileiros. Do que se trata?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

De [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francesinha):

> ### Francesinha é um prato típico e originário da cidade do Porto, em Portugal.
>
> A francesinha tem a forma de uma sanduíche e é constituída por linguiça, salsicha fresca, fiambre, carnes frias e bife de carne de vaca ou, em alternativa, lombo de porco assado e fatiado, coberta com queijo posteriormente derretido. É guarnecida com um molho à base de tomate, cerveja e piri-piri. Os acompanhamentos de ovo estrelado (no topo da sanduíche) e batatas fritas são facultativos.

#### Francesinha com ovo e batatas fritas

[image: Francesinha com ovo e batatas fritas]

Acho que não tem nada a ver com . . . alguma outra coisa divertida. :)

Comment: **yum**, it's 1.30 p.m. and I haven't had lunch yet.

Comment: ah, o Porto..! Que beleza de lugar